# Should an api changes other systems state before returning response?

Tags: rest, architecture, software-design

I have a question about system/api design.
Lets say, there are two components - component A and component B.
component A need some information (say charges) from component B.
So, component A makes a POST call to component B with the required request data.
component B computes the charges by calling multiple systems, 
post them to component C and then returns them to component A.

Condition here is that the data posted to component C and data returned to component A should exactly match and this data can change at any point in time. (that is why component B post this data to component C before sending it back to component A).

Now, in my opinition the api provided by component B to component A is not concise.
It is trying to do multiple things - It seems to be a mix of both GET and POST.
It is non-idempotent(which POST actually is) 
but from the perspective of component A it should be idempotent.

I would very much like to have your views on it. What is the best way to design it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the API and therefore have an entirely different approach to these problems based on manufacturing.

First, stop yourself when you say "A needs information from B." Programmers 99/100 times think this means B needs to push data to A. I see you conceptualized the problem as "A requests data from B", but you still assume a need for A/B communication, because you assume B owns the data.

Integration means A and B collaboratively work on the same data, without any communication and without the data product being considered owned by either. That's how you should conceptualize the problem, not as a need to deliver from producer to consumer, but as a need to integrate two modules or systems to operate on the same data. Communication only adds complexity and couples the modules. Manufacturing's approach eliminates *all* communication.

Code for my manufacturing architecture can be found here:

http://www.powersemantics.com/power.html

When you ask about system/API design, be aware APIs force consumers to directly communicate. Because APIs must be immediately (manually) controlled, they don't integrate. Production process modules, which I call "custom" or "DSL" machines, however can be programmatically controlled and bound to the same data, which eliminates logistics steps (and reading them) from your code. It's no exaggeration POWER replaces the API. Welcome to tomorrow.